# Mongodb $external database cannot create new user with user defined role

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have created a user defined role with collection access privileges in admin db. Since our mongodb is using X.509 authentication mechanism, I have to create user in $external database. In this $external db, it cannot find the role I created in admin db.

In $external db, I run command in mongo shell:

```
db.createUser({user:"xxxxx", roles:["custom_role"]})
```

Error showing:

```
[thread1] Error: couldn't add user: No role named custom_role@$external
```

How can I create a user in $external db and assign it to a user defined role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a user defined role in admin db first. Next, switch to $external db and specify the role comes from admin db like this:

```
db.createUser({user: "xxxx", roles:[ { role : <user created role name>, db : "admin" } ]})
```